# req.body.content giving undefined - Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I am new to node & express. I tried to create a sample API of note application.

When I tried to test API by creating a new note using POSTMAN, I am getting undefined as the value of req.body.title & req.body.content. But when I tried to console req.body I am getting the following:

```
 { '{"title": "Chemistry Note", "content": "Lorem ipsum note clasds"}': '' }
```

I am using latest version of express, bodyParser, mongoose.

This is the note.controller.js file

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body.title);
    // Validating request
    if(!req.body.content) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: "Note content cannot be empty"
        });
    }

    // Creating a Note
    const note = new Note({
        title: req.body.title || "Untitled Note",
        content: req.body.content
    });

    // Saving Note
    note.save()
        .then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Note."
            });
        });
};
```

This is server.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// Creating Express Application
const app = express();

// Parse request of content-type - application/x-www-form-url-encoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// Parse request of content type - application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const dbConfig = require("./config/database.config");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

// Using native promises
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// Connecting to Database
mongoose.connect(dbConfig.url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connected to the database");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("Could not connect to the database. Exiting now...", err);
    process.exit();
});

// Define a simple route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({"message": "Welcome to Note Application"});
});

// Require Notes routes
require("./app/routes/note.routes.js")(app);

// Listen for requests
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});
```

Below is note.model.js file:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

// Defining Schema
const NoteSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

// Creating Model with this schema
module.exports = mongoose.model('Note', NoteSchema);
```

Below is note.routes.js file:

```
module.exports = (app) => {

    // Contains the methods for handling CRUD operations
    const notes = require("../controllers/note.controller.js");

    // Creating new Note
    app.post('/notes', notes.create);
};
```

Please help, thank you. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might be better served by actually posting the ["Minimal Code to Reproduce the Problem"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as opposed to just asking people to read a tutorial article and also trust you actually did include the code you were supposed to. The error and output would seem to suggest a "body-parser" is not correctly set up. Also the sample "document" appears malformed, so there possibly is an issue there as well. If you give people something to **exactly** reproduce, then spotting the problems is easy. Read the link and learn from it.

Comment: @NeilLunn : Thanks for the info. Can you please check now?

Comment: As has sort of been posted as an answer already, your request appears malformed. At a guess I would say your POSTMAN request forgot to change from "form encoded" to "raw". So you end up with your JSON document as an empty pair and represented as the key name. I have a personal dislike of tutorials that use pictures instead of code, but take a good look at the picture and you should see the option you appear to have forgotten to change.,

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for the kind info. I forgot to change the format from text to JSON. This is due to lack of big picture view in postman. Thank you.

Comment: If you're using Postmon to send requests, make sure to choose `JSON` in the `Body`. The default `Text` wouldn't work and will give out this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ '{"title": "Chemistry Note", "content": "Lorem ipsum note clasds"}': '' }, 
it's not a object you want. 
For this json your key is '{"title": "Chemistry Note", "content": "Lorem ipsum note clasds"}'. 
And its don't have any key like title, content.

Change above object to
{"title": "Chemistry Note", "content": "Lorem ipsum note clasds"}
```

Comment: @Biplalb  : Thankyou. Can you guide me how can I change the object? I got this when doing console req.body

Comment: Try this code, JSON.parse(Object.keys({ '{"title": "Chemistry Note", "content": "Lorem ipsum note clasds"}': '' })[0])

Comment: Actually I am posting the above data with postman, not in code. I think the JSON data in request body is not getting parsed using body-parser. But I am sure that that order in which middle ware declared is correct. Can you kindly check the code?

Comment: In postman you need to send body data format 
select body tab, then checked raw and then select Json(application/json) from dropdown. and then in editor of postman paste this code
{"title": "Chemistry Note", "content": "Lorem ipsum note clasds"}

also you can do in node,
const obj = JSON.parse(Object.keys(req.body)[0])

Comment: @DeepeshKumarR, can you make a question that how to send json object from postman, beacuse I think lot of starter facing same issue, and share the link with me

Comment: Sure will make one.